# Short story about the ultimate paradox: Computer tries to solve the riddle "I always lie" and causes the lab to shut down

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read a sci-fi short in the early 70's in an anthology. It was not at that time I do not believe a recent print. A man lives in a space lab. His computer can solve anything. The man gave a riddle something like this: "I always lie". That is a true statement. Computer than dedicated all its resources to solving that puzzle. Lab is shut down. Man dies.

Comment: Obviously [not Portal 2](https://youtu.be/kzsl-qPNyfY?t=52)

Comment: Lots of examples at https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LogicBomb

Comment: Your question has been closed as a Duplicate. This is not meant as a censure, but it is rather just a sort of bookkeeping we do when story-identification questions share the same answer. You will still get points for upvotes, and people can comment on it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The Monkey Wrench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey_Wrench) by Gordon Dickson is set on a Venus weather stati, not a space station but otherwise fits.

From the linked Wikipedia description:

> Despite that, Cary happily makes a bet that he could gimmick the machine in one minute. He successfully does so by throwing at the machine a metaphoric monkey wrench - a paradox:
> You must reject the statement I am now making to you, because all the statements I make are incorrect.
> With the Brain dedicating all of its banks to working on the paradox, the consequence of Cary's action finally bears down upon the pair, as the harsh negative temperatures of Venus rapidly sets in.

Comment: That does sound very close, and the publishing date is in the ball park. The space lab losing air could have been another one in that or another anthology. Did read a lot of those at that time.

Answer (score 6):

Not in space, but a very similar story that you may be remembering as it does involve a logic bomb shutting down the computer and causing the death of the man that asks the question:

In Gordon R. Dickson's story [The Monkey Wrench](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Monkey_Wrench), a man attempts to shut down a meteorologic arctic station just for bragging rights. He is able to do so by submitting a logical paradox to the computer , making it incapable of doing anything than solving the paradox. Unfortunately this causes him and his partner to freeze to death, as all the major environment controls were provided by the computer.

Comment: It definitely was a space lab. It may have been a weather satellite, but would not sware to that detail. He died because the computer shut down the air system to dedicate everything to that paradox.